# Hot to fix corruption of taskbar (multiple language panels) in Terminal Services in Win2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal, language, windows

Hot to fix corruption of taskbar (multiple language panels) in Terminal Services in Win2003?
I know how to close many language panels and then check one.
How to disable occurrence  multiple language panels after log-in terminal session ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932039) from Microsoft for "Language bar is displayed two or more times on the taskbar"

You can also try disabling it with these: [eggheadcafe](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=32141454&threadid=32141452) or [technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winserverGP/thread/1efaf2b3-ae87-419e-a632-85af2e145075/) articles.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the task bar - Toolbars - click one of the many checked "Language Bar" entries.
Now you have one language bar less. Repeat this process until they are all gone

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the language bar at all, you can use the following to rack it off completely:

1. Start
2. Control Panel Regional and Language
3. Options Select Languages Tab, click Details
4. In 'Text Services and Input Languages' click Advanced Tab
5. Place a check mark in 'Turn off Advanced Text Services'

This should disable the language bar completely.